# JQuery Form Validation: Error Message not displayed when there is escaped JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

The script below works great, but today I came across a scenario I think is being caused by escaped JSON.

As you'll see in the code below, I'm using remote validation to return error messages in JSON format as required.

On particulr error message being returned that looks like this is not being displayed: 
*{"valid":false, "error":"XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found **'\"'** (0x0022)"}*

My suspicion is that it's due to the escaped double quote (in bold above).

I suspect this because a similar error message that looks like this displays just fine: *{"valid":false, "error":"XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found ''' (0x0027)"}*

I tried messing with escaping things further but to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form-validate').validate(); 
    $("[name^=customfields]").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            remote: {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/xpath-evaluator.xqy",
                dataType: "json",
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (json.valid != false) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {return "\"" + json.error.split(')')[1] + "\"";}
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `'\"'` for s**ts and giggles? Seeing as `\"` is technically one character ..

Comment: Sorry, should have added that, I did try changing to single quotes and all other manner of quoting and escaping I could come across to no avail. Changing to single quotes broke both of my examples above actually.

Comment: Not that one, then! Just to check if that is the cause, have you tried removing the escaped quote and recreating the error? As in removing it from the JSON message*

Comment: Thanks for the tips! While I couldn't change the message coming back from the remote system, I realized I could use replace to escape the '\"' that was causing the issues and finally have the error display. I'm answering this post with with updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not change the remote response coming back I used replace to escape the character it was having trouble with, in this case it was the **'\"'** as shown in the error below:

*{"valid":false, "error":"XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found **'\"'** (0x0022)"}*

Here's the updated Javascript showing how I did it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form-validate').validate(); 
    $("[name^=customfields]").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            remote: {
                type: "GET",
                url: "/xpath-evaluator.xqy",
                dataType: "json",
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (json.valid != false) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                    var jerror = json.error.split(')')[1]
                    return '\"' + jerror.replace('\"', '\\"') + '\"'}
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks are in order to Sippy who commented and set me on the right track to fixing this. Hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Bah, I did nothing! Congrats on finding a solution :)